# A reasonable solution for accessing iCloud numbers with Python

Tags: python, api, numbers, icloud

The company where I work is full of pretty complex processes. This is all magnified by the IT situation that is extremely manual involving multiple (16+) checklists for processes lasting several weeks, redundant excel spreadsheets, proprietary accounting software, and vastly different computer competence levels within the team.

I am a relatively inexperienced programmer now taking it upon myself to write software that will eliminate much of the redundancy while opening up information that is there but not accessible. I am doing most of it, for now, in php and html but the automation part is python. I have encountered several points that are above my programming ability but am handling them pretty well so far. The biggest problem, and the reason I am here, is, predictably, the owner.

He has an Apple and uses iCloud numbers. It is the only Apple on the network. I have searched a lot for any sort of API access via python. There is something out there that but I can only find info about accessing where a telephone is or access contacts on a telephone. I'm not familiar with iCloud and may be coming at this the wrong way, Idk. I only need to do simple reading and writing to a single spreadsheet one cell at a time.

I have thought about Selenium but that seems too complicated for me right now.

Does anyone know of an API to access iCloud Numbers or have a better idea?

Thnx in Advance

Comment: Hello @bsbaixo, do you have any sample code that you can share? Have you looked at Apples API documentation? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have seen it and am reviewing it again. There seems to be a lot about how to authenticate but not so much on what you can do once your there.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested any of this code nor have I implemented any of this, but in GitHub there is a library called `pyicloud` that seems like a channel to get access to files. This is untested code, but iCloud Numbers data should be accessible, and it seems you should be able to do something like this:

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService
icloud = PyiCloudService(apple_id,password)
icloud.drive().get_file(file_id)
```

Again, all untested and unverified. See more info here: https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud

Best of luck!

Comment: awesome, I'll try it out!